# The code from GetStream.io documentation doesn't work in RN. <Text> string must be inserted

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, getstream-io

I am using Firebase Server on Node together with RN. I wanted to use GetStream.io in my app. The backend works fine, but an example from GetStream.io documentation for frontend doesn't work, I just get this error.

[image]

I tried to insert  attribute though it doesn't exist in GetStream.io example. I still receive this error.

This is how my code looks like:

```
  import React from 'react';
  import SafeAreaView from 'react-native-safe-area-view';
  import { StreamApp } from 'react-native-activity-feed';
  import { Text, View } from "react-native";

  const newsFeed = () => {
   return (
     <View>
      <SafeAreaView style={{flex: 1}} forceInset={{ top: 'always' }}> 
        <StreamApp
      apiKey="myapikey"
      appId="myappid"
      token="mytoken"
  />
    </SafeAreaView>
  </View>
  );
 };

 export default newsFeed;
```

https://getstream.io/react-native-activity-feed/tutorial/ link to official guide from GetStream.io

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it seems like your `newsFeed` component is rendered inside a Text element.

Here's the link to the check in RN that raise this error -> https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Components/View/View.js#L44

Eg. this JSX code would trigger the same error:

```
<Text>
   < newsFeed />
</Text>
```

Assuming this is the case (or a variation of it) you can fix this problem very easily by wrapping your component in a `<View>` and remove `<Text>` when not necessary.

Comment: But I don't have      <Text> in my component

Answer (score 0):

So what I found out.

The problem was because of this line:

```
 import SafeAreaView from 'react-native-safe-area-view';
```

What you should do is following:

```
 import { SafeAreaView } from "react-native";
```